# How to define that a function returns an object when building binding for a iOS library

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios

Building a wrapper for an iOS library. So far so good. Except in a method that returns an object. Method always returns NSObject instead. The same story is in delegate that has an object  parameter .

For example,TCConnection is defined in Monotouch binding project as

```
//@interface TCConnection : NSObject 
    [BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
    public  interface TCConnection 
    {

        [ExportAttribute("state")]
        int state {get;}

    //...
    }
```

class TCDevice is defined as follows

```
//@interface TCDevice : NSObject 
[BaseType (typeof(NSObject))]
public interface TCDevice
{
    [ExportAttribute("initWithCapabilityToken:delegate:")]
    IntPtr Constructor(String token, TCDeviceDelegate d);

    [Export("connect:delegate:")]
    TCConnection Connect([NullAllowed] NSDictionary param, [NullAllowed] TCConnectionDelegate del);

}
```

Everything is compiled nicely to a dll.
When I use the dll in other project, I call

```
MyTCDeviceDelegate d=new MyTCDeviceDelegate();
String token="XXXXX";
TCDevice dev=new TCDevice(token, d); 
TCConnection conn=dev.Connect(null,null);
```

The last line always throws Invalid Cast exception.It looks like the method returns NSObject.

What I am missing here?

Comment: You're definitely missing the 'accept' button...

Comment: Bindings looks ok - but we have nothing (ObjC headers) to compare them to...